# String manipulation for a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following record in quotestable:

```
| quotesid | quotestags         |
+----------+--------------------+
| 123      | Friendsip, Courage |
```

I have the following query:

```
 update quotestable 
 set quotestags = COALESCE(quotestags, '') + ', Friendship' 
 where quotesid = 123

 update quotestable 
 set quotestags = COALESCE(quotestags, '') +', Courtesy' 
 where quotesid = 123
```

In the first query I am trying to append `Friendship` tag in the quotestag column but that value is already there. How do I check its duplicity? If the value is there donot add it. If the value is not there then add it.

Comment: This is bad design. Store each quotestag separatelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DEclare @Table TABLE( quotesid INT, quotestags VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 123 ,'Friendship, Courage' UNION ALL
SELECT 124 ,'Friendship, Courage' UNION ALL
SELECT 125 ,'Relationship, Courage' UNION ALL
SELECT 126 ,'Sincere Courage'

--SELECT quotesid,quotestags,CHARINDEX('Friendship',quotestags) from @Table

UPDATE t
SET quotestags=COALESCE(o.quotestags, '') + ', Friendship' 
from @Table t
INNER join @Table o
ON o.quotesid=t.quotesid
WHERE CHARINDEX('Friendship',t.quotestags)=0

SELECT * from @Table
```

Result

```
quotesid    quotestags
-----------------------------------------------
123         Friendship, Courage
124         Friendship, Courage
125         Relationship, Courage, Friendship
126         Sincere Courage, Friendship
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something simple like below

```
update quotestable 
 set quotestags = COALESCE(quotestags, '') + ', Friendship' 
 where quotesid = 123 and NOT quotestags like '%Friendship%'

 update quotestable 
 set quotestags = COALESCE(quotestags, '') +', Courtesy' 
 where quotesid = 123 and NOT quotestags like '%Courtesy%'
```